# Using id to manipulate data and bootstrap to style

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm a newbie with Bootstrap and I want to know if it is a bad practice to use Id's to manipulate some data with Jquery along side with the classes of bootstrap for the styles, at first it seems a wrong thing to do.

For ex:

I Have an Ajax call and i want to populate the table with the info.

Assuming i Get a result from ajax = `Field1||Field2||Field3`

```
function PuxaProduto()
{
    var id_prod = $('#produto').val();
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: 'POST',
        url:'comercial_busca.php', 
        data:
        {
            puxa_prdo:id_prod
        },
        success:function(result)
        {    
            var dataArray = result.split("||");
            $('#id_estado').html(dataArray[0]);
            $('#id_cidade').html(dataArray[1]);
            $('#id_bairro').html(dataArray[2]); 
        }
    });
}
```

And the table:

```
<div class="row hide" id="container2" >
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <table class="table table-bordered col-md-12 text-center">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td id="id_estado"><strong>Estado: </strong></td>
                    <td id="id_cidade"><strong>Cidade: </strong></td>
                    <td id="id_bairro"><strong>Bairro: </strong></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is it a bad practice?
And if yes, how can i make it good?

Comment: you are on right track according to me

Comment: just you have to make sure of no duplicate ids

Comment: `Field1||Field2||Field3` strange format. Why can't you use JSON instead and do not reinvent the wheel? :)

Comment: @YuryTarabanko Thats how I have learned to use it, assuming that I get a result like this: FirstElementfield1|FirstElementfield2||SecondElementfield1|SecondElementfield2
the entire ex would be something like this:
var dataArray = result.split("||");
var html_output = "|";
for(i = 0; i < dataArray.length - 1; i++)
{
    var itemArray = dataArray[i].split("|");

    $('#id_estado').html(itemArray[0]);
    $('#id_cidade').html(itemArray[1]);
    $('#id_bairro').html(itemArray[2]); 
}
how do I do that with JSON?
If its better I want to learn!!
=]
Tks

Comment: What if any of the values actually contains '||'? With json you can make it more robust. Check this demo http://jsfiddle.net/HKPta/1/ The code is more DRY. 
Server respond with something like `{"estado":"whatever it is :)"...}`. You then can use `result.estado` field whatever way you need.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko
That Way is indeed way better!!!
From now on I'll do it just like that!
Tks!
:D

Comment: Or take a look at Knockout http://knockoutjs.com/. I'm quite sure it has all you need. :)